# How to call my logout functionality when the user closes the browser without clicking on logout button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC+Jquery application.
I want to execute a specific functionality which deletes some records when the user logs out. I want to call the same action method if the user closes the browser without clicking on logout.
Is there a way to do this in MVC or JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No. I am wondering on how do I handle this, as I was thinking if something in global.asax can handle this

Comment: aren't you using `session` why do u care if user click on logout or close browser directly . you should be asking for credentials again until unless he storing in cookies etc after session exit .

Comment: I have to delete some records from db on logout or on browser close

Answer (score 0):

You could use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event. When user tries to go out of your app, execute your function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  //Do your stuff here..
};
```

Comment: This is not a reliable solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: deleteUrl,         // Location of the service
    data: "",       //Data sent to server
    contentType: "",        // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true,  //True or False
    success: function (json) {//On Successful service call
        $('#logout').click() // trigger logout button
    },
    error: ServiceFailed    // When Service call fails
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but how are you associating this with browser close event? Please let me know.

Comment: Please add window.close()

Comment: Where should I add this ?

Comment: after logout click event